# Python wildcard search in string

Tags: python

Lets say that I have a list

```
list = ['this','is','just','a','test']
```

how can I have a user do a wildcard search?

Search Word: 'th_s'

Would return 'this'

Answer (score 212, accepted):

Use [`fnmatch`](http://docs.python.org/library/fnmatch.html):

```
import fnmatch
lst = ['this','is','just','a','test']
filtered = fnmatch.filter(lst, 'th?s')
```

If you want to allow `_` as a wildcard, just [replace](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) all underscores with `'?'` (for one character) or `*` (for multiple characters).

If you want your users to use even more powerful filtering options, consider allowing them to use [regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html).

Comment: Cool :) But I understand that is it tuned to match paths, won't it act funny if slashes are present? Also, does it support the `**` wildcard? (e-> I've checked the docs- it doesn't treat slashes differently and so the `**` wildcard isn't even necessary here).

Comment: The documentation states that `fnmatch` is "Unix filename pattern matching".  But I just tried it, and it seems to work on Windows.  Is this lucky undefined behavior, or is `fnmatch` supported on Windows?

Comment: @cowlinator The method of filename matching is called _Unix file matching_ because it originated with Unix, but it is operating system-independent, in the same way that arabic numerals also work in English.

Comment: The filter just works with lists as argument. In case of string I need a re.

Comment: @Timo You can try `fnmatch.fnmatch` or `fnmatch.fnmatchcase` which accept string as first param

Comment: I prefer `fnmatchcase` if not strictly using it for os-independent filename matching. Because `fnmatch` will vary its case-sensitivity depending on the os . So INsensitive on windows, Sensitive on unix/linux/macos, etc (presumably - haven't tested windows, but I see it uses posixpath.normcase)

Answer (score 63):

Regular expressions are probably the easiest solution to this problem:

```
import re
regex = re.compile('th.s')
l = ['this', 'is', 'just', 'a', 'test']
matches = [string for string in l if re.match(regex, string)]
```

Comment: This shouldn't be accepted answer (regex doesn't process wildcard matches) - e.g. I'm looking for pure wildcard solution (given by @phihag) and I'm already familiar with regex

Comment: how does regex not process wildcard matches??

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean any specific syntax for wildcards? Usually `*` stands for "one or many" characters and `?` stands for one.

The simplest way probably is to translate a wildcard expression into a regular expression, then use that for filtering the results.

Comment: The `fnmatch` module has a function to translate wildcard matches into regular expressions: [**`fnmatch.translate`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html#fnmatch.translate)

Comment: It seems that * is for zero to more, at least it works for me because I need a string that sometimes has NOT the searched char..

Answer (score 0):

Same idea as Yuushi in using regular expressions, but this uses the findall method within the re library instead of a list comprehension:

```
import re
regex = re.compile('th.s')
l = ['this', 'is', 'just', 'a', 'test']
matches = re.findall(regex, string)
```

Comment: you still need to get string from an array somehow.

Comment: But.... what is `string`?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use the join function? In a regex findall() or group() you will need a string so:

```
import re
regex = re.compile('th.s')
l = ['this', 'is', 'just', 'a', 'test']
matches = re.findall(regex, ' '.join(l)) #Syntax option 1
matches = regex.findall(' '.join(l)) #Syntax option 2
```

The join() function allows you to transform a list in a string. The single quote before join is what you will put in the middle of each string on list. When you execute this code part (' '.join(l)) you'll receive this:

'this is just a test'

So you can use the findal() function.

I know i am 7 years late, but i recently create an account because I'm studying and other people could have the same question. I hope this help you and others.

---

Update After @FélixBrunet comments:

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r'th.s')
l = ['this', 'is', 'just', 'a', 'test','th','s', 'this is']

matches2=[] #declare a list
for i in range(len(l)): #loop with the iterations = list l lenght. This avoid the first item commented by @Felix
if regex.findall(l[i]) != []: #if the position i is not an empty list do the next line. PS: remember regex.findall() command return a list.
    if l[i]== ''.join(regex.findall(l[i])): # If the string of i position of l list = command findall() i position so it'll allow the program do the next line - this avoid the second item commented by @Félix
        matches2.append(''.join(regex.findall(l[i]))) #adds in the list just the string in the matches2 list

print(matches2)
```

Comment: would not this solution break if there was the word "th" and "s"? (by joining, you would get "th s", with would be a valid match.
also, if there was already in the list a string with space like "this is", your solution would return "this" event it there was no element in the list exacly fitting. this could be a problem.

Comment: @FélixBrunet, you are absolutely right! I wrote a code with a loop that avoid the itens you have mentioned! How I'm in a learning process, I believe this could be improved. If you have something more to add, please fell free. Thank You.