# how to compare two strings ignoring few characters

Tags: python

I want to compare two strings in python ignoring some characters, like if the string is:

```
"http://localhost:13555/ChessBoard_x16_y20.bmp"
```

I want to ignore the values `"16"` and `"20"` in the string; no matter what these values are, if the rest of the string is same as this string is then I should get the result `"TRUE"`. How can I do this?

Example:

```
URL = "http://localhost:13555/ChessBoard_x05_y12.bmp"

if URL == "http://localhost:13555/ChessBoard_x16_y16.bmp":
    print("TRUE")
else:
    print("FALSE")
```

Output:

```
TRUE
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11427138/python-wildcard-search-in-string

Comment: you may use regular expression `http:\/\/localhost:13555\/ChessBoard_x\d+_y\d+\.bmp`

Comment: Are these fixes position? In other words, will it always be two digits where you currently have 16 and 20?

Comment: if you want to ignore the last bit of the string (I assume it always has the same format), just cut it out before the comparison: `s = inputstring[:-7]`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). Here it is for your case. A dot matches any symbol. A \d matches a digit. Some special symbols have to be escaped.

```
import re
if re.match(r'http://localhost:13555/ChessBoard_x\d\d_y\d\d\.bmp', URL):
    print("TRUE")
else:
    print("FALSE")
```

Comment: As those symbols will be digits, you could use `\d` instead of `.`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you will be able to do this with regex

```
>>> import re
>>> CHESS_BOARD_PATTERN = r'http://localhost:13555/ChessBoard_x\d+_y\d+.bmp'
>>> def is_chess_board_endpoint(endpoint):
...     return bool(re.match(CHESS_BOARD_PATTERN, endpoint))
... 
>>> is_chess_board_endpoint('http://localhost:13555/ChessBoard_x16_y20.bmp')
True
>>> is_chess_board_endpoint('http://localhost:13555/ChessBoard_x05_y12.bmp')
True
>>> is_chess_board_endpoint('http://google.com.br')
False
```

But it is obvious that depending on your solution, you have to improve this regex, because if you change the host (from localhost to 192.168.0.10 for example) will not work.

Answer (score -1):

```
def checkstrings(string1, string2):
    if len(string1) != len(string2):
        return False
    for x in range(len(string1)):
        if x == 35 or x == 36 or x == 39 or x == 40:
            continue
        if string1[x] != string2[x]:
            return False
    return True
```

JAVA:

```
public static boolean checkStrings(String string1, String string2){
        if(string1.length() != string2.length()){
                return false;
        }
        for(int x = 0; x < string1.length(); x++){
                if(x == 35 || x == 36 || x == 39 || x == 40){
                        continue;
                }

                if(string1.charAt(x) != string2.charAt(x)){
                        return false;
                }
        }
        return true;

}
```

Comment: They don't mean the 16th and 20th characters, they mean the two values. Also, don't compare strings by identity (`is`), use equality (`==`).

Comment: Comparing strings by equality only checks if either one of them is a string. I tried that before in Python and it messed up sometimes

Comment: *"Comparing strings by equality only checks if either one of them is a string"* - that is completely untrue.

Comment: Thanks jonrsharpe, I'll keep that in mind. Sorry, I'm also a beginner :P

Comment: I also have a question, should I get the entire next integer at that position since it could be of different length?

Answer (score -2):

You can loop through characters in the string and check if they are digits or not. I.e.

if x.isdigit():

Comment: Unbelievable unuseful post. Think about regular expressions or string format patterns...