# Match two wildcard strings

Tags: python, regex, string

I just learned how to match a string with a wildcard from (very helpful) [Python wildcard search in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11427138/python-wildcard-search-in-string)

Now I'm trying to match two strings that both have wildcards.

```
string1 = "spotify.us.*.uk"
string2 = "spotify.*.co.uk"
```

These two strings should be a match. Using `*` will be used as wildcard. My research online shows no solution. What I have so far (not working):

```
import re

string1 = "spotify.us.*.uk"
string2 = "spotify.*.co.uk"
r1 = string1.replace("*", ".*")
r2 = string2.replace("*", ".*")
regex1 = re.compile('.*'+r1)
regex2 = re.compile('.*'+r2)

matches = re.search(regex1, regex2)
```

I used the same concept to match a `string` and a `regex` which was a working. But it doesn't work in this case where both string have wildcards. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact those two strings should *not* be a match, because a regular expression is always comparing a pattern to a string.  There's no such thing as evaluating whether a pattern matches another pattern, outside of validating if both patterns match a common string -- it's just outside the expressiveness of the language.

`re.search()` takes as the first argument a pattern (as a compiled pattern or pattern string) and as the second argument a string.  It returns whether that pattern matched on that string.  Passing two pattern will throw a `TypeError`

Now assuming you pass in `re.search(regex1, r2)` it will not error out, but will not find a match.  Why?  Well `regex1='.*spotify.us..*.uk'` (in terms of expressiveness) which means "match anything containing any number of non-newline characters, followed by `spotify`, followed by any single (non-newline) character, followed by `us`, followed by two or more non-newline characters followed by `uk`.  Indeed, the literal string `spotify..*.co.uk` does not match this description.

### Aside:

Considering that `.` means match any non-newline character and `\.` means match a literal dot, you probably wanted something like:

```
regex1 = "spotify\.us\..*\.uk"
regex2 = "spotify\..*\.co\.uk"
```

### Aside #2:

If you are only using wildcards, [`fnmatch`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html#fnmatch.fnmatch) (e.g. glob-style matching) is sufficient to express the same patterns and looks a lot cleaner in this case:

```
regex1 = "spotify.us.*.uk"
regex2 = "spotify.*.co.uk"
fnmatch.fnmatch('spotify.us.foo.uk', regex1)
# Output: True
```