# Accessing header string-value of an Excel cell

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, header, openpyxl

I have a table on an Excel file (.xlsx) that I created with Python 2.7: [image: table]

On the first column, you can see the individuals (geometries) that are checked (respectively '*3001*', '*3002*' and '*3003*'). All geometries have a *RelativeThickness* law, a *MaxThickness* law and a *position of the maximum thickness* law, evolving along the geometry. There are criteria (not shown here) that say "*OK*" or "*N.OK*" (not OK) if the criteria of a certain law is not respected.

**For example :** the laws evolving along the geometries are in fact curves. If I put a criteria "*Only allow 1 maxima on the curve*" on the law "*MaxThickness*" and I apply this criteria to my 3 individuals, it's made to put '*OK*' for *3001* and *3002* and '*N.OK*' for *3003* (+ coloring red or green) since *3001* and *3002* only have 1 maxima along the curve but *3003* has 2 maxima. The global effect of all the criteria on all the laws is summarized in the "*TOTAL*" column.

I would like to go through each one of my rows and to check when there's a "*N.OK*". If there's a "*N.OK*" I would like Python's code to return me the header concerned (**for example :** Python wouldn't return me anything for *3001* and *3002* but for *3003* it would return me "*MaxThickness*", "*MaxThicknessPosition*" and "*TOTAL*").

It would be like this (but I don't know how to access the header and return its string value) :

```
for row in sheet1.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_col=6, max_row=4):
    for cell in row:
        if cell.value == 'N.OK':
            header = cell.header
```

"sheet1" is my active sheet on the Excel file (wb=Workbook() and sheet1=wb.active).

**Important :** I have to stay on Python 2.7 and I can't use pandas (I can't use cmd window to use conda, anaconda, miniconda, pip,... because I can't have admin access) and I already tried to download and install it manually but I have a problem with the C files that are compressed in it. I found [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34296132/how-to-use-field-name-or-column-header-in-openpyxl) but I'm not sure I understand how it works.

If this is possible, I would also like to "ignore" the "TOTAL" column. I would need to print or to store why an individual is rejected (based on what law that is not respected) to be able to say "*3003 is rejected because of MaxThickness and MaxThicknessPosition*" but I don't want to print or to store "TOTAL is not respected".

Thank you very much if you can help me with this !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to create something to look up the headers.

```
headers = dict((c.column, c.value for c in ws[1]))

for row in ws.iter_rows((min_row=1, max_col=6, max_row=4):
    for cell in row:
        if cell value == "N.OK":
             header = headers[column]
```

For what it's worth I think it's pretty idiotic for someone coming to Python to be forced to work with Python 2.7. Libraries, including openpyxl, will soon no longer work with Python 2.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I just had to remove one ")" and one "(", and to add one ")" after "c.value" and I had to add "." between "cell" and "value" and I had to change "headers[column]" by "headers[cell.column]" to make it work. 
But thank you, I have now exactly what I wanted without using any additional modules I'm so thankfull for that ! Have a great day ! :)