# Rename header column names in Excel files using Python?

Tags: python, excel

I am new to python and I want to rename the header column names in an Excel file.

In the input file all the content is in capital letters.
I want to convert that into title-case (first letter capital and rest small).

#### Example

For example from `MKT` to `Market`:

[image: Input file picture]

Comment: What did you try? E.g. using [OpenPyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34296132/how-to-use-field-name-or-column-header-in-openpyxl) ..please share your code-attempt as [example].

Answer (score 0):

To change MKT in Market you're gonna have to use dictionnaries as there is no easy for the program to translate MKT into Market.

```
aliases = {"MKT": "Market", "US": "United States"} # You can expand the dict.
# Then try something to get all the headers in a list
headers = [put your headers in here somehow]
for index, value in enumerate(headers):
    if header in aliases.keys():
        header = aliases[header]
        headers[index] = header
```

As for changing the capitals:

```
str = "ANY STRING"
str = str.lower().capitalize()
```

Comment: Okay but I  want to change all the column name in one go then

Comment: could you edit your post and show us how your database is setup and what we have to work with ? Such as example lists or dicts containing your data. Basically the input we have and an example of the output you want.