# Looking for numeric characters in a single word string PYTHON

Tags: python

I have a variety of values in a text field of a CSV

Some values look something like this 
AGM00BALDWIN
AGM00BOUCK

however, some  have duplicates, changing the names to
AGM00BOUCK01
AGM00COBDEN01
AGM00COBDEN02

My goal is to write a specific ID to values NOT containing a numeric suffix

Here is the code so far

```
prov_count = 3000
prov_ID = 0
items = (name, x, y)
xy_tup = tuple(items)

if "*1" not in name and "*2" not in name:
    prov_ID = prov_count + 1
else:
prov_ID = ""
```

It seems that the the wildcard isn't the appropriate method here but I can't seem to find an appropriate solution.

Comment: You can check the last 2 characters using `name[-2:]`. What is the max number of duplicates in your data?

Comment: Is it possible that a non-duplicate ends with a number, or if you see things like `01`, `02`... at the end of the name, that will unequivocally mean that it's a duplicate?

Comment: try with name.endswith(("1", "2"))

Comment: @Farhan.K I cant see any more than 2 digits worth of duplicates

Comment: `"*1"` is not a wildcard, it is checking the literal character `"*"` if you want to do wildcard see [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11427138/python-wildcard-search-in-string)

Comment: @Whitty21 That is going to confuse future readers. You should leave your original code that everyone provided answers for

Comment: @Farhan.K I didnt think about that, and have restored it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use slicing to find the last 2 characters of the element and then check if it ends with `'01'` or `'02'`:

```
l = ["AGM00BALDWIN", "AGM00BOUCK", "AGM00BOUCK01", "AGM00COBDEN01", "AGM00COBDEN02"]

for i in l:
    if i[-2:] in ('01', '02'):
        print('{} is a duplicate'.format(i))
```

Output:

```
AGM00BOUCK01 is a duplicate
AGM00COBDEN01 is a duplicate
AGM00COBDEN02 is a duplicate
```

Or another way would be using the `str.endswith` method:

```
l = ["AGM00BALDWIN", "AGM00BOUCK", "AGM00BOUCK01", "AGM00COBDEN01", "AGM00COBDEN02"]

for i in l:
    if i.endswith('01') or i.endswith('02'):
        print('{} is a duplicate'.format(i))
```

So your code would look like this:

```
prov_count = 3000
prov_ID = 0
items = (name, x, y)
xy_tup = tuple(items)

if name[-2] in ('01', '02'):
    prov_ID = prov_count + 1
else:
    prov_ID = ""
```

Comment: I simplified it as a test and this isn't working, though it looks like what I was thinking in my head

Comment: name = ["AGM00BALDWIN", "AGM00BOUCK", "AGM00BOUCK01", "AGM00COBDEN01", "AGM00COBDEN02"]
for i in name:
    if name[-2] in ('01', '02'):
        print "bad"
    else:
        print "good"

Comment: @Whitty21 which part doesn't work? Do you get an error message? the snippet you posted in your second comment should work fine

Comment: I have got it working using an unsimplifeid approach. Now I just seem to have an issue with my loop, as every value is being written as null

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to do it, one with the `isdigit` function:

```
a = ["AGM00BALDWIN", "AGM00BOUCK", "AGM00BOUCK01", "AGM00COBDEN01", "AGM00COBDEN02"]

for i in a:
  if i[-1].isdigit():  # can use i[-1] and i[-2] for both numbers
    print (i)
```

---

Using `regex`:

```
import re
a = ["AGM00BALDWIN", "AGM00BOUCK", "AGM00BOUCK01", "AGM00COBDEN01", "AGM00COBDEN02"]

pat = re.compile(r"^.*\d$")  # can use "\d\d" instead of "\d" for 2 numbers
for i in a:
  if pat.match(i): print (i)
```

another:

```
for i in a:
    if name[-1:] in map(str, range(10)): print (i)
```

all above methods return inputs with numeric suffix:

```
AGM00BOUCK01
AGM00COBDEN01
AGM00COBDEN02
```

Comment: I thought about using isdigit, but I think the 00 space holder in the middle wrecks that idea.

Comment: use `isdigit` just on the last character. I did that in my example.

Comment: @Whitty21 It doesn't because only the last character is being checked

Answer (score 1):

Using regular expressions seems appropriate here:

```
import re

pattern= re.compile(r'(\d+$)')

prov_count = 3000
prov_ID = 0
items = (name, x, y)
xy_tup = tuple(items)

if pattern.match(name)==False:
    prov_ID = prov_count + 1
else:
    prov_ID = ""
```

Comment: You can use `if not pattern.match(name)` instead of `if pattern.match(name)==False`