# Filter list of string elements with wildcard and append into list

Tags: python

I am trying to append object upon searching a certain keyword into individual lists, with something as follows:

```
dict_list = defaultdict(list)
query_all_tags = ... #some other funcs that will generate dict of lists...

# Example output of query_all_tags
#['limit_projA', 'limit_remote_server10', 'limit_remote_server2', 'limit_alias']
#['limit_projB', 'limit_remote_server10', 'limit_alias']

for tag in query_all_tags:
    if 'limit_remote_server2' in tag:
        dict_list['server2'].append(tag)
    if 'limit_remote_server10' in tag:
        dict_list['server10'].append(tag)
```

If using the above example above, I will get first the element (the one with 'limit_projA') in both `server2` and `server10` list.

Then I tried to use `count` to filter out if it checks whether `tag` has more than 1 `limit_remote_server` (like a wildcard) as follows:

```
for tag in query_all_tags:
    if tag.count('limit_remote_server') > 1:
        dict_list['misc'].append(tag)
    if 'limit_remote_server2' in tag:
        dict_list['server2'].append(tag)
    if 'limit_remote_server10' in tag:
        dict_list['server10'].append(tag)
```

but it appears that `count` is not working as it will return me a `0` value instead.

What is the best approach I should do then?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `count()` doesn't do wildcard, nor should it, since you just placed the text without any hint of what the wild card is supposed to be.

Anyhow, you can use a combination of `re` and `map()` to get what you want:

```
my_count = lambda my_pattern, my_list: sum(list(map(lambda x: re.match(my_pattern, x) is not None, my_list)))
for tag in query_all_tags:
    if my_count(r'^limit_remote_server\d+', tag) > 1:
        dict_list['misc'].append(tag)
    elif 'limit_remote_server2' in tag:
        dict_list['server2'].append(tag)
    elif 'limit_remote_server10' in tag:
        dict_list['server10'].append(tag)
```

If you want your code to be more readable, don't use lambda and instead define the functions the old fashioned way.  Also, use `elif` after the count to avoid them executing even after you've already appended to `dict_list['misc']`.

You can also use `fnmatch` as mentioned in an abundance of similiar quesitons: [Python wildcard search in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11427138/python-wildcard-search-in-string)