# How to list objects based on prefixes with wildcard using Python Boto3?

Tags: python, boto3

I need to find all the files with a specific prefix. For example:

```
raw/client/Hist/2017/*/*/Tracking_*.zip
```

I tried this line of code but it does not work:

```py
    import boto3
    client = boto3.client("s3", aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key)
    client.list_objects(Bucket="myBucket", Prefix="raw/client/Hist/2017/*/*/Tracking_*.zip")
```

Comment: The [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects) on the `Prefix` parameter explicitly says >Limits the response to keys that begin with the specified prefix. So you'll need to get all keys starting with `raw/client/Hist/2017/` then filter them further yourself.

Comment: @Eric Bellet Did you get a solution using prefix wild card . I am trying to figure out

Comment: Hi, unfortunately no

Comment: @Kar See accepted answer if you are still looking for a solution.

Comment: You could consider using fnmatch https://stackoverflow.com/a/11427183

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You won't be able to do this using boto3 without first selecting a superset of objects and then reducing it further to the subset you need via looping. However, you could use Amazon's [data wrangler](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-data-wrangler) library and the [list_objects](https://aws-data-wrangler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/stubs/awswrangler.s3.list_objects.html#awswrangler.s3.list_objects) method, which supports wildcards, to return a list of the S3 keys you need:

```
import awswrangler as wr
objects = wr.s3.list_objects('s3://myBucket/raw/client/Hist/2017/*/*/Tracking_*.zip')
```

Comment: Does this actually work for you in practice?

Comment: Of course - otherwise I wouldn't have posted it as an answer.

Comment: It doesn't work for me!

Comment: Ok, well you can always start a new question with your specific problem.

Comment: As of version 3.4.0 it appears to still support this wildcards-in-prefix feature: https://aws-sdk-pandas.readthedocs.io/en/3.4.0/stubs/awswrangler.s3.list_objects.html#awswrangler.s3.list_objects